# .htaccess: WordPress MS in root, xenForo in subdir, rewrite parked domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website at http://rplstoday.com -- WordPress is installed in the root and xenForo is installed at /community. I have another domain (http://beerleg.com) pointing there, but I want everything to point at their respective rplstoday.com locations. That is:

- beerleg.com --> rplstoday.com
- beerleg.com/community --> rplstoday.com/community
- beerleg.com/community/blahblah --> rplstoday.com/community/blahblah

Here is what I currently have in .htaccess in root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beerleg.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.beerleg.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://rplstoday.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The default xenForo .htaccess in /community is untouched, and looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    #RewriteBase /community

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, here's what really happens:

- beerleg.com --> rplstoday.com
- beerleg.com/community --> beerleg.com/community
- beerleg.com/community/blahblah --> beerleg.com/community/blahblah

As you can see, the rewrite only occurs for the base domain, but not when going to any internal URLs. My lack of knowledge (and inability to find fixes via Google) has me stumped. I would deeply appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing, thanks to some help from the support team at xenForo.

In the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beerleg.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.beerleg.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://rplstoday.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the /community .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beerleg.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.beerleg.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://rplstoday.com/community/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Turned out to be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.rplstoday.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

This should redirect your domain with the full path. However, you can also try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.rplstoday.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up finding a solution, but I appreciate your help. :-)